# How to set a base template for jinja2 in python?

Tags: python, jinja2

With jinja2 i can use `{% extends "base.html" %}` in the template. But i want to set a default base template in the python code, like this:

```
t=environment.get_template(filename)
t.render(base_template="base.html")
```

So i do not need to add the `extends` line to each template, when all templates (must) use the same base template.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, because Jinja actually compiles the templates into Python code and `{%extends%}` affects the output. By the time when you call `render` it's already too late.

Comment: Maybe an easy way (no rewriting of the loader) to create an jinja2.Environment, which has a base_template property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an own loader:

```python
class FileSystemLoaderWithBase(jinja2.FileSystemLoader):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.base_template = kwargs.pop("base_template", None)
        super(FileSystemLoaderWithBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_source(self, environment, template):
        (source, path, creation) = super(
            FileSystemLoaderWithBase, self).get_source(environment, template)
        if self.base_template and template != self.base_template:
            source = '{% extends "' + self.base_template + '" %}\n' + source
        return (source, path, creation)
```

It can be used with a base-template name:

```
l=FileSystemLoaderWithBase("mytemplatefolder", base_template="base.html")
```

optionally you can allow loading templates with own `{% extends "..." %}` line to enable some templates to have more complex inheritance with

```
if self.base_template and template != self.base_template\
    and "{% extends" not in source:
```

This is of course not very robust. For example the number of spaces between `{%` and the `extends` keyword is allowed to be different in jinja2 templates.